# Problems on iRedMail installation

Tags: email, email-server

I'm trying to install iRedMail 0.8.5 on a CentOS 6.5 using MySQL backend, but I'm getting the following dependencies error messages at the end of the proccess:

```
Transaction Check Error:
file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0 from install of mariadb-libs-5.
5.33a-1.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package compat-mysql55-5.5.34-1.el6.
    remi.x86_64
file /usr/libexec/dovecot/managesieve conflicts between attempted installs of
dovecot-1:2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64 and dovecot-managesieve-2:0.2.6-22.el6.x86_64
file /usr/libexec/dovecot/managesieve-login conflicts between attempted installs of      dovecot-1:2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64 and dovecot-managesieve-2:0.2.6-22.el6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/dovecot/lib90_sieve_plugin.so conflicts between attempted inst
alls of dovecot-pigeonhole-2:0.2.6-22.el6.x86_64 and dovecot-1:2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/dovecot/libdovecot-sieve.so.0.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs   of  dovecot-pigeonhole-2:0.2.6-22.el6.x86_64 and dovecot-1:2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Can you show us the installation command you're running, and tell us where you got the RPM?

Comment: I've got the rpm from iRedMail's site. I did the untar and executed the installer as explained in the doc (http://www.iredmail.org/install_iredmail_on_rhel.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doco to which you refer says (*inter alia*)

> For CentOS or Scientific Linux, please enable CentOS/Scientific
>   official yum repositories, and DISABLE all third-party yum
>   repositories to avoid package conflict.

I see that at least one of the RPMs above comes from a 3rd party repository (`compat-mysql55-5.5.34-1.el6.remi.x86_64`, which I think is from `http://rpms.famillecollet.com/`).  You will need to uninstall all conflicting RPMs before you can go ahead with installing this tool.

**Edit**: yes, that should be possible via `yum`, try (for the first one)

```
yum remove package compat-mysql55
```

and see how that goes.  The bigger problem will be why they were installed in the first place, are there databases running that need the updated packages, etc.  If this isn't a clean install, if there are functions on this machine already, you will need to **think** before doing this.

Comment: do you know any way of removing the conflicting packages via yum?

Comment: It's very strange. When I try to remove the package as you described, I get:

No Match for argument: compat-mysql55
Package(s) compat-mysql55 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Then it's probably not installed (confirm with `rpm -qa|grep compat-mysql55`?), just getting wrongly pulled in by the dependency management done when installing the redimail package.  Have you removed the remi repository from the list in `/etc/yum.repos.d`?

Comment: People, I had to rebuild my enviroment. I've installed iRedMail on a new and fresh system. I got it without any troubles. I recommend to install iRedMail before anything on the enviroments.
Thanks!